# How can I use "Reduce" to solve equation with complicated form?

Tags: equation-solving

Here I used `Reduce` to solve that complicated equation in complexes but MMA didn't give an answer after a few mins. I wonder whether there're some functions could solve equations like that or not in MMA. Much appreciation if help!

```
equation=-1. (-4. + z^2) (2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4) + (-0.5 + z)^2 (-4. + z^2) (2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4) + 0.125 (-HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z - Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]] + HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z + Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]]) - 0.75 (-0.5 + z) (1. Sqrt[2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4] (-HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z - Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]] + HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z + Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]]) + z Sqrt[-4. + z^2]Sign[-1 + Norm[0.595238 (-2.32 + z^2 + Sqrt[2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4])]]);
Reduce[equation==0,z,Complexes]

(* Out: Reduce[equation==0,z,C] plus a warning message. *)
```

Comment: What warning do you get?

Comment: @MarcoB.I didn't have enough reputations to comment so I post warning message here:<br>
Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.

Answer (score 1):

```
equation=-1. (-4. + z^2) (2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4) + (-0.5 + z)^2 (-4. + z^2) (2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4) + 0.125 (-HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z - Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]] + HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z + Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]]) - 0.75 (-0.5 + z) (1. Sqrt[2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4] (-HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z - Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]] + HeavisideTheta[1 - Norm[0.5 (-z + Sqrt[-4. + z^2])]]) + z Sqrt[-4. + z^2]Sign[-1 + Norm[0.595238 (-2.32 + z^2 + Sqrt[2.56 - 4.64 z^2 + z^4])]]);
FindInstance[equation == 0, z, Complexes]
```

> `{{z -> -0.413422 + 0.0363153 I}}`

Comment: `FindInstance[equation == 0, z, Complexes,2]` produces a message "FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist" and returns the input.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I used `FindInstance` but only got one root as same as you and I'm quite sure there're more than one root for that equation.

Comment: Indeed, `NMinimize[{ComplexExpand[Abs[equation /. z -> x + I*y]], 
  x >= 0.4134220 && y <= 2 && y >= -2}, {x, y}]` results in `{6.85182*10^-10, {x -> 0.801364, y -> -0.0234891}}`.